# I would like to get size of youtube video without downloading in scrapy or python

Tags: youtube

I would like to get size of youtube video without downloading, ist it possible for below link?

https://youtu.be/hkuUVjlBOVs

Comment: would the size depend on some factors, EG resolution?

Comment: https://noembed.com/embed?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkuUVjlBOVs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file size without downloading a YT video with pytube.

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/hkuUVjlBOVs')

print(yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().filesize)
```

Output file size in bytes:

```
4410471
```

Return all available resolutions:

```
for i in yt.streams:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
<Stream: itag="17" mime_type="video/3gpp" res="144p" fps="6fps" vcodec="mp4v.20.3" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="18" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="25fps" vcodec="avc1.42001E" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">
<Stream: itag="134" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="25fps" vcodec="avc1.4d4015" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="243" mime_type="video/webm" res="360p" fps="25fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="396" mime_type="video/mp4" res="360p" fps="25fps" vcodec="av01.0.01M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="133" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="25fps" vcodec="avc1.4d400d" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="242" mime_type="video/webm" res="240p" fps="25fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="395" mime_type="video/mp4" res="240p" fps="25fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="160" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="25fps" vcodec="avc1.4d400b" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="278" mime_type="video/webm" res="144p" fps="25fps" vcodec="vp9" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="394" mime_type="video/mp4" res="144p" fps="25fps" vcodec="av01.0.00M.08" progressive="False" type="video">
<Stream: itag="139" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="48kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.5" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="140" mime_type="audio/mp4" abr="128kbps" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="249" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="50kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="250" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="70kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
<Stream: itag="251" mime_type="audio/webm" abr="160kbps" acodec="opus" progressive="False" type="audio">
```